# Rename [dungeons-dragons-online] → [dungeons-and-dragons-online]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I'd like to propose renaming the tag for Dungeons & Dragons Online from [dungeons-dragons-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-dragons-online) to [dungeons-and-dragons-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons-online). Presumably the tag was created back when tags were limited to 25 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch, done so. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons-online?tab=Votes